# Do the gyroids in Club LOL have any affect on the songs played in Club LOL?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

For example, will having 4 Nebuloids increase the chance of either performer playing a certain song. This of course would be convenient if you happen to be missing certain music.

Comment: Aren't the gyroids always the same? I could swear they're always the same 4 gyroids, but maybe that's just during setup/saturday nights (that's usually when I go)

Comment: You can change them out yourself during the week by going up to them and 'talking' to them.

Comment: Ohhhh cool, I didn't know that. Do you have to brng your own gyroids or does it just let you pick?

Comment: You bring your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't have any effect on what song is played. They "[perform](http://www.thonky.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/club-lol/)" while K.K. is playing.

Comment: The thing is, it is not outside the realm of possibility that having a set of 4 on stage may 'inspire' K.K. to play certain music, ESPECIALLY since they perform on stage.

Comment: @Reafexus The gyroids accompany K.K. while he is DJing, during which you can't get copies of songs anyway. There is nothing to suggest they'd do anything while K.K. is playing the guitar.

Comment: Ah ok. I thought they accompanied him during both. That makes sense. Thanks.